# Reserve Email Addresses for old users within Exchange organization

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2013, exchange-2019

Due to a software dependency, I have an odd requirement in my environment, while trying to clean up stale accounts. **I want to remove all the stale AD Users and Exchange mailboxes from the environment, however, I need to somehow reserve the SMTP Address for the stale account, so that the address cannot be assigned to another mailbox later** (maybe a new user with the same name). I'm looking for the best strategy. technical details are not my concern.

I've ended up with the below two strategies (I think still there must be a better way, please advise):

1. convert each mailbox to a contact. Steps:

   - remove mailbox (this will also delete the AD user)
   - create a contact with the email address of the deleted mailbox
     Cons: not much cleanup! because each object is actually replaced by another object.
2. preserve all email addresses by adding each as a proxy address for a dummy user. Steps:

   - remove mailbox (this will also delete the AD user)
   - add the email address of the deleted mailbox as a proxy (additional) address into a dummy mailbox
     Cons: I have more than 6000 stale mailboxes. in exchange 2019 you can have ~1000 addresses per object.

another approach might be a "Disable-and-then-Enable-mailbox" strategy, which will remove all the old mailbox contents, preserves the address, and also preserve the user account. like the <1> method mentioned earlier, it actually does not clean up much.

**What do you think is the best way to preserve a lot of email addresses in the Exchange Server (or Active Directory), and avoid those addresses from being assigned to new users after the original mailbox is deleted?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Delete the mailbox and user account.
2. Create a Distribution Group and name it using a name that describes it's purpose (like Placeholder or something to that effect), then hide it from the Address Book, and then add the email addresses as aliases for the Distribution Group.

Comment: interesting. I've never thought about the Distribution Group idea. this leaves no user and mailbox trace!. it's great already. however I'm curious about that is there anything special about using the Distribution Group instead of a dummy account/contact? I mean some limitation that User/Contact may have? or just because it's safer?

Comment: There's nothing special about a DG or a Contact. They're just placeholders for the email addresses. If it were me, I'd use a DG.

Comment: Glad to see the issue has been resolved:)